# List all the questions from deleted accounts

Tags: support, search, deleted-accounts

When an account is deleted it has an ID like `user123456`.

Is there a way to search for questions whose OP has deleted the account? In other words, I want to list all the questions from deleted accounts.

How can I do that?

Comment: On the site, or on SEDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to do this with regular site search, but the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) may help. You'll have to search for `Posts` with `PostTypeId = 1` (questions) and `OwnerUserId IS NULL` (that means there's no link to the owner, because it has been deleted). [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1330134/questions-by-deleted-users) does so; feel free to fork it to add additional search terms (e.g. score, tags, or parts of the body).